# Escaping question mark in mySQL regex

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have this simple query that uses regex. I don't know why it returns an error every time I try to run it.

```
select *
from mytable
where thumbnail_url regexp '^\?.+'
```

Basically, I want to see if any string in this list starts with a question mark or not.
I am connected to Amazon RDS through MySQLWorkbench 6.3.

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: Error Code: 1139. Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp

Comment: Double the backslash. MySQL requires the first one to escape the second backslash which so it can be treated as a literal character in the regex (to modify/escape ?) rather than as an escaping character within the SQL itself. Thus use regexp '^\\?.+'

Comment: Regex is valid https://regexr.com/3md2b

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you use a backslash to escape a regexp character in MySQL, you must also escape the backslash itself as `\\`. MySQL would see a single `\` character and attempt to use it as an escaping character within the SQL statement itself rather than treating it as a literal. But you need it to act as a literal in order to modify the `?` within the regex.

The first `\` escapes the second `\`, resulting in a literal regex sequence `\?` to represent a single literal `?` in the matching string.

[MySQL documentation on string literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html)...

Format your expression with an escaped backslash as:

```
select *
from mytable
where thumbnail_url regexp '^\\?.+'
```